# when creating a new case, is there a way to show a flag or pop-up that states Active/Inactive on an account field, or when the account is select

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I will be feeding the account object with the list of deactivated accounts, and flag it with a "Y" id active.
I would like one of two things to happen; when you select the account, if its flagged Y/1, then flag the case creation window with the text Y", or add a popup to state that the account is deactivated.
The other option is for it to Not allow the case to be created if the account is deactivated.

is there a way to do this?